# Using Googles FastButton with jQuery .on() method

Tags: jquery

I have implemented https://github.com/alexblack/google-fastbutton on my mobile app and it works perfect, however I was wandering whether it can be used with jQuery `.on()` method.

Something like this

```
$(document).on('fastClick', '.element', function() { });
```

I've tried the above but it doesn't seem to work.

Has anyone had this issue before and did you make it work?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the google-fastbutton, this is the way to do it

```
$('#your-button').fastClick(function(e) {
    alert('fast clicked!');
});
```

Comment: Yes, that method works fine. But the problem I'm having is I don't want to declare it everytime a dynamic element is added to the DOM. I want it to work the same way the .on() method works. Any ideas?